# Spring Boot REST application; findBy method using foreign key

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

Using Spring Data REST, I have two models, NvdApps with a one-to-many relationship to NvdVulnerabilities

I'm trying to add the ability to search NvdVulnerabilities by an NvdApp, so my repository looks like this:

```
public interface NvdVulnerabilityRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<NvdVulnerability, Long> {
    List<NvdVulnerability> findByNvdApp(NvdApp nvdApp);
}
```

And this gives me the REST end point:

```
"findByNvdApp" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/nvdVulnerabilities/search/findByNvdApp{?nvdApp}",
      "templated" : true
    }
```

When I try to use this end point, it just returns the entire table, regardless of what I put in the query string. Example URL's I've tried:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/nvdVulnerabilities/search/findByNvdApp?nvd_app_id=25
http://localhost:8080/api/nvdVulnerabilities/search/findByNvdApp?25
http://localhost:8080/api/nvdVulnerabilities/search/findByNvdApp?NvdApp=25
```

Am I missing some configuration? I'm basically trying to replicate the query:

```
SELECT * FROM NVD_VULNERABILITY where nvd_app_id = 25
```

Which works as intended in the H2 database console. How exactly does the search end point work, and how do I get it to filter as intended?

I'd also like to have the paging work with the search endpoint; right now it returns the entire 7k+ rows whereas the end point `http://localhost:8080/api/nvdVulnerabilities/` returns 20 items per page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
List<NvdVulnerability> findByNvdApp_Id(Integer id);
```

If `Integer id` variable exists in your `NvdApp` class.

Comment: Okay great, that does work. Is there any way to enable paging as well?

Comment: Figured it out, adding it to my question, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Changing the repository query to match below:

```
public interface NvdVulnerabilityRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<NvdVulnerability, Long> {
    Page<NvdVulnerability> findByNvdApp_Id(Long id, Pageable pageable);
}
```

allows searching by id as well as making the return paginated